# How to move an org-mode file together with all attachments?

Tags: org-mode

I have a couple files, e.g. `file-1.org`, `file-2.org` in the same directory sharing the `data/` directory for attachments.

I'd like to move `file-1.org` to a different location, create a new `data/` directory in that location and move all attachments that belong to `file-1.org` to the new directory. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: That sounds useful, but doesn't seem to exist. The simplest option may be to move the files directly and then use `org-attach-sync` to sync them with the new item.

Comment: Maybe, moving the linked files is not such a good idea. It might be that the files in the data folder are referenced in other org-files where the links break if these files disappear. **Oh no, there are no such org-files** ... _until you become aware of the broken links in the special case you never thought about before_ ;-). Maybe, copying is the better alternative. Or one should at least search for the most obvious cases (e.g., org-files with links in the same folder).

Comment: Are the org files managed by a version control system, like git? When I add attachments to an org file in git, the attachments are automatically committed to the repository.

Comment: org-lint may help find broken links

Answer (score 2):

This command could do what you want:

```
find -E data -type f -iregex ".*($(cat file-1.org | grep -i ':id:' | perl -pe 's/^\s*:id:\s*(\w{2})([\w-]+)$/$1\\\/$2/i' | paste -s -d'|' -)).*" -exec rsync -R '{}' ~/temp/my-new-directory \;
```

Replace `file-1.org` with the org file whose attachments you want to move, and `~/temp/my-new-directory` with the location of your new directory. A `data` directory will be created with the attachment files in them (if you want to move instead of copy, pass `--remove-source-files` to the `rsync` command).

This was tested on macOS. You might have to omit the `-E` flag on other platforms.

**NOTE:** *Please* do this on a *copy of your files*. I'm not an expert in emacs, have never used org-mode attachments and I'm not experienced with using this kind of hacky file manipulation. This could blow your org-mode folder into oblivion so back it up first.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Marcel Samyn's answer, the following script worked for me under ArchLinux:

```
find data -regextype awk -type f -iregex ".*($(cat file-1.org | grep -i '^:id:' | perl -pe 's/^\s*:id:\s*(\w{2})([\w-]+)$/$1\/$2/i' | paste -s -d'|' -)).*"  -exec rsync -R '{}' ~/temp/my-new-directory \;
```

Use the following reduced script to get a list of files to be copied:

```
find data -regextype awk -type f -iregex ".*($(cat file-1.org | grep -i '^:id:' | perl -pe 's/^\s*:id:\s*(\w{2})([\w-]+)$/$1\/$2/i' | paste -s -d'|' -)).*"
```

Without the `^` in the grep command, I got false positives from email links containing ":id:".